# Explanation for mount -t and mkfs

Tags: filesystems, mount

What is the purpose of specifying which type of file system will be mounted with argument [-t] if you previously already used mkfs.[whatever] to format your HDD/flash drive?

I have no problem in doing so, I just want to understand the logic behind:
    mount -t

Comment: In most case you won't need `-t` and mount will figure out the file system type. There are times when it can't figure out thus the need to specify the filesystem type. There are times when a filesystem needs to be mounted as a different filesystem Take `ext3` for example. `Ext3` is simply an `ext2` with journaling. In cases where journaling is damaged or you want to bypass it, you can then mount an `ext3` as `ext2` by specifying `-t`.

Comment: And there's also the historical/portability reason: implementations of `mount` without filesystem autodetection, where `-t` isn't optional.

Answer (score 3):

The `-t` switch is for explicitly stating which filetype you want to use, which can be useful for ambiguous filesystems.  For example, a small hard drive from a Windows 98 machine could be either `vfat` or `fat32`.  The `-t` switch tells `mount` to explicitly use a specific filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

The `mount` command can be thought of as a bit of a frontend command for a whole host of filesytem mounting commands. There are these which are actual executables that can be called to do the heavy lifting of mounting for their respective filesystem types.

```
$ ls /usr/sbin/ | grep mount
mount.cifs
mount.fuse
mount.glusterfs
mount.lowntfs-3g
mount.nfs
mount.nfs4
mount.ntfs
mount.ntfs-3g
mount.ntfs-fuse
```

**NOTE:** But this is just a partial list. There are other types that `mount` can deal with as well. These are built into the Linux Kernel.

Because it's structured this way the concept of mounting can be applied to a variety of filesystem types. You can explicitly tell `mount` via the `-t` switch what type of filesystem the target you're attempting to mount is.

The man page for `mount` contains many more types that `mount` is able to contend with.

*excerpt*

```
   -t, --types vfstype
          The  argument  following the -t is used to indicate the filesystem 
          type.  The filesystem types which are currently supported include: 
          adfs, affs, autofs, cifs, coda, coherent, cramfs, debugfs, 
          devpts, efs,  ext, ext2, ext3, ext4, hfs, hfsplus, hpfs, iso9660, 
          jfs, minix, msdos, ncpfs, nfs, nfs4, ntfs, proc, qnx4, ramfs, 
          reiserfs, romfs, squashfs, smbfs, sysv, tmpfs, ubifs, udf,  ufs,  
          umsdos,  usbfs, vfat,  xenix,  xfs,  xiafs.   Note  that  
          coherent, sysv and xenix are equivalent and that xenix and               
          coherent will be removed at some point in the future — use sysv 
          instead. Since kernel version 2.1.21 the  types ext and xiafs do 
          not exist anymore. Earlier, usbfs was known as usbdevfs.  Note, 
          the real list of all supported filesystems depends on your kernel.
```

#### Under the hood

You can use the `strace` command to see some of what's going on when different filesystem types are mounted.

#### Examples

The following commands were run as root.

*CIFS*

```
$ strace mount -t cifs -o username=sam //bart/mp3s-1 /mnt
...
stat("/sbin/mount.cifs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=41024, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f2469308b50) = 21593
wait4(-1, Password for sam@//bart/mp3s-1:  *************
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 21593
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=21593, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

*NFS*

```
$ strace mount -t nfs mulder:/export/raid1/data /mnt
...
stat("/sbin/mount.nfs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0755, st_size=110720, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fc76c957b50) = 22017
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 22017
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=22017, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

*ISO file via loopback*

```
$ strace mount -o loop /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive/monitoring/FAN/FAN-2.3-x86_64.iso /mnt
...
mount("/dev/loop0", "/mnt", "iso9660", MS_MGC_VAL|MS_RDONLY, NULL) = 0
```

So with the above examples, you can see in some cases mount is doing the mounting directly, as with the ISO via loopback, while in the other examples it's cloning itself and then calling the `mount.<filesytem>` within a child stack.